# Compute all properties of a Vue.js state object in Chrome Devtools console?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I want to inspect some live data on a Vue instance in Chrome I have to click into the object in order to see any data because of how all the values have been converted to getters and setters.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jSt0.png) image contains an example of what I mean. I had clicked the `name` property of the object at index `0` of the array and only then could I see the value as being the string "Perpetual". It is incredibly annoying when I just want to see an overview of my data at a glance.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyRdX.png) is an example of what I really want. As you can see, by using `JSON.stringify` inside of `JSON.parse` I removed the "observability" from the object and now it can easily be inspected at a glance in the console.

Obviously doing this every single time is even more of a hassle (and also not an options if my data has `RegExp` objects or other data which isn't JSON compatible) than clicking through the array and clicking object properties I want to compute, but hopefully it helps to show what I'm after.

Somebody please tell me there's a better way to do this. I just want Chrome Devtools to just automatically compute all the values of getters in objects I print to the console so I don't have to click through my data structures all the time in order to get a quick overview of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for the Vue Chrome Devtools extension which is awesome: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

It also features the vue component tree, editable data and props, events, time travel debugging and router support.

[image: Vue Devtools]